# Intersection observer Animated elements already on page sporadically working

Tags: javascript, frontend, intersection-observer

I am trying to animate elements using intersection observer but I'm getting odd behaviour from elements already on the screen at page load.

They randomly sometimes animate correctly and other times do not.

```
const faders = document.querySelectorAll('.fade-in');
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

const appearOptions = {
    threshold: 0,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px -200px"
};

const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver((entries, appearOnScroll) => {

    entries.forEach(entry =>{

        
        if (!entry.isIntersecting){
            return
        }

        else{
            entry.target.classList.add("appear");
            appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    })
}, appearOptions);



faders.forEach(fader => {
    appearOnScroll.observe(fader);
});

sliders.forEach(slider => {
    appearOnScroll.observe(slider);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that this issue only occurs while dev tools is open in chrome browser.

The animations work consistently if devtools is closed!

Comment: Return doesn't break forEach. Not sure of what behaviour is intended.